# Google Apps Script - 2 dimension variables

Tags: google-apps-script

I do not really understand, how to create 2 dimension variables/arrays in Google Apps Script. The following code provides the same result (12), even the variables are different. What am I doing wrong?

```
function test(){
var Latitude = [20,20];

Latitude[1,2] = 15;
Latitude[5,2] = 12;

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1').setValue(Latitude[5,2]);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B1').setValue(Latitude[1,2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Two dimensional arrays are **arrays nested inside a array**:  `[[1,2],[3,4]]`
- Inner arrays are rows: `[1,2]`
- Elements of inner array are column values: `1`
- Array values can be accessed with index: `row1 = arr[0]; row1Col1 = arr[0][0]`
- [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in JavaScript evaluates each expression and returns the value of the last expression.

This snippet demonstrates what happens:

```js
function test() {
  var Latitude = [20, 20]; //1D array

  Latitude[(1, 2)] = 15; //([1,2]) is evaluated as [2],the third element
  console.log('Latitude is now:'); //[20,20,15]
  console.log(Latitude);
  Latitude[(5, 2)] = 12; //Again setting [2] as 12
  console.log('Latitude is now:'); //[20,20,12]
  console.log(Latitude);
  console.info('Latitude[18,1] is:' + Latitude[(18, 1)]); //=Latitude[1]
  console.info('Latitude[18000,1] is:' + Latitude[(18000, 1)]); //=Latitude[1]

  /** 2D Array example */
  console.info('2D ARRAY:');
  var arr2d = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
  console.info('arr2d === ' + JSON.stringify(arr2d));
  arr2d.map(function(row, i) {
    console.info('Row' + i + ' is array: ' + JSON.stringify(row)); //=arr[i]
    row.map(function(column, j) {
      console.info('Column is: ' + column); //=arr[i][j]
      console.info('arr2d[' + i + '][' + j + '] is: ' + arr2d[i][j]);
    });
  });
}
test();
```

#### To practice:

- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. This is confusing compared to VBA. What is the shortest way to get a simple 2d-variable?

Comment: @Dirk I'm not sure what you mean. I guess create it: `arr2d=`...Vba is a moribund language though

Comment: I tried arr2d as you proposed, but I cannot use any range. I would like to store any value e.g. i = 1 to 200 / j = 1 to 200. But `arr2d = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];` leads to errors.

Comment: @Dirk A new question would be better. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Explain your use case. The language you're coming from is fundamentally different from js.